# vb.net threading.thread addressof passing variables

Tags: vb.net, parameter-passing, addressof

I am trying to pass some status from a IP call in a shared sub to a label on my form.

This is the current code that i am using:

```
Class Server
    <STAThread()> Public Shared Sub Main()
        Dim aTcpMessaging As IMessagingSystemFactory = New TcpMessagingSystemFactory()
        Dim anInputChannel As IInputChannel = aTcpMessaging.CreateInputChannel(theIPforLocal & ":" & thePort)
        Dim aStringMessagesFactory As IStringMessagesFactory = New StringMessagesFactory()
        Dim aStringMessageReceiver As IStringMessageReceiver = aStringMessagesFactory.CreateStringMessageReceiver()
        AddHandler aStringMessageReceiver.MessageReceived, AddressOf StringMessageReceived

        aStringMessageReceiver.AttachInputChannel(anInputChannel)
    End Sub

    Private Shared Sub StringMessageReceived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As StringMessageEventArgs)
        LANResponse = Convert.ToString(e.Message)
        Dim lanSent As String() = Nothing
        Dim sep(3) As Char
        Dim s As String = ""

        sep(0) = "~"
        'sep(1) = ","
        lanSent = LANResponse.Split(sep, 2)

        Dim a As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf getStatus)

        a.SetApartmentState(Threading.ApartmentState.STA)
        a.Start(Trim(lanSent(0)) & Trim(lanSent(1)))
  End Sub
End Class

Private Shared Sub getStatus(ByVal data As Object)
    lblStatus.text = ("Static: " & data)
End Sub
```

The error its giving me is on the line **lblStatus.text = ("Static: " & data)**

> Error 1   Cannot refer to an instance member of a class from within a shared method or shared member initializer without an explicit instance of the class.

Any help would be great!

David

**UPDATE**

After adding:

```
Private Sub getStatus(ByVal data As Object)
    If InvokeRequired Then
        Invoke(New Action(Of Object)(AddressOf getStatus), data)
    Else
        lblStatus.Text = ("Static: " & data)
    End If
End Sub
```

I get this error no one line **Dim a As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf getStatus)**

> Error 1   Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'New' can be called with these arguments:
>       'Public Sub New(start As System.Threading.ParameterizedThreadStart)': Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference.
>       'Public Sub New(start As System.Threading.ThreadStart)': Method 'Private Sub getStatus(data As Object)' does not have a signature compatible with delegate 'Delegate Sub ThreadStart()'.

Comment: Did you address my "Step three" and "Step four"? For the giggles, put in Server, `Public Shared refToMyForm as MyFormClass` (where `MyFormClass` is the class name of your form), then change `AddressOf getStatus` to `AddressOf refToMyForm.getStatus`.

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed you're trying to make this work using `Shared` members. That may be problematic for the following reasons:

(1) Without the `Shared`, behind the scenes a reference variable is created, and it is called `Me`. Via `Me` you can get to `lblStatus`, such as `Me.lblStatus`, and actually one doesn't necessarily need to put in the `Me`, one could specify `lblStatus` by itself. But, even by itself, the `Me` is implied there, and is still used.

(2) With the `Shared`, there is no `Me`. Without the `Me`, there is no `lblStatus` instance for the compiler to identify - hence the error. 
You will need to find some way to pass in a reference to your Form from which to access `lblStatus`. I need to warn you, though, that updating a Label or other user interface class directly from a thread other than the main thread is regarded as something bad - this is because WinForms is not thread-safe. Beginning with .NET Framework 2, you'll get an error if you try (although it is possible to opt-out of this error, at your own peril).

These are for C#, but it may give you some ideas on how to proceed:

[How to update the GUI from another thread in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661561/how-to-update-gui-from-another-thread-in-c)

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23517/How-to-Properly-Handle-Cross-thread-Events-and-Upd

So step one is to make getStatus not a shared member - that will bring back the `Me`.

Step two is to redesign getStatus into a thread-safe form for getting the text into the Label, such as:

```
Private Sub getStatus(ByVal data As Object)
    If InvokeRequired Then
        Invoke(New Action(Of Object)(AddressOf getStatus), data)
    Else
        lblStatus.Text = ("Static: " & data)
    End If
End Sub
```

Step three is to find some way to get a reference to your Form into `Server` - may be via a shared ArrayList? Or just some shared reference to Form?

Step four is a redesign of StringMessageReceived so that the `AddressOf` portion is now in the form of `AddressOf refToMyForm.getStatus`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Delegate
 Example for your case:

```
Public Delegate Sub AddLabelTextDelegate(ByVal label As LabelControl, ByVal value As String)

Public Sub AddLabelText(ByVal label As LabelControl, ByVal value As String)
    label.Text = value
End Sub
```

Then from your other thread you need to invoke:

```
        Me.lblStatus.Invoke(New AddLabelTextDelegate(AddressOf AddLabelText), New Object(){lblStatus, "Value"})
```